# Reference a range froma different sheet

Tags: arrays, vba, range, runtime-error, histogram

I'm trying to create a program that optimizes histogram bin width...before that though, I need help with a seemingly simple task - setting a Range mentioned in a cell into a VBA array.

I'd like the data for the histogram to be on any sheet, in this case 'Data'!B4:M12. This is mentioned in D4 of the sheet I want the histogram to appear on. I keep getting an error when I run my code though, even after changing it multiple times. There's clearly a syntax error that I don't know how to handle.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

```
Sub Histogram_Shimazaki_Shinomoto()

Dim data_range As String, min_bins As Integer, max_bins As Integer
Dim Data()
Dim x_min As Double, x_max As Double

data_range = Cells(4, 4)    ' data range
min_bins = Cells(5, 4)      ' min # of bins
max_bins = Cells(6, 4)      ' max # of bins

Set Data = Range(data_range)

x_min = WorksheetFunction.Min(Data)

MsgBox x_min

End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set an array of variant equal to a Range -- but that isn't possible since you can't assign to an array. You could assign a range to a simple `Variant` (or to a `Range` variable). You could change

```
Dim Data()
```

to

```
Dim Data as Variant
```

Note the absence of parenthesis. Also, as a stylistic point I think that it is good to be explicit about the type, even though `Variant` is the default.

This might be enough for your code to work, although if all you want is the minimum *value* in the range, you could change

```
Set Data = Range(data_range)
```

to

```
Data = Range(data_range).Value
```

If the sheet  "Data" isn't the active sheet and `data_range` contains "B4:M12" then you would need to use

```
Data = Sheets("Data").Range(data_range).Value
```

since `Range` returns a range on the active sheet unless explicitly qualified by a reference to the sheet.